# New tag proposal - anarchy

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, winning-criteria, new-genre

This is not to be confused with [anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org), which it is named after.
This tag means that each language has its own leaderboard, and the leaderboard will not only list the answerer, but any editors as well. This can be overridden by a statement with a specific format at **the very end** of the post:

> By <submitter/largest contributor> with help from [<user>].

Score should usually be relative to the best answer in the same language. Example:

`score = s/b` where `s` is the size of your answer and `b` is the size of the best answer, and `1` is the best score.

Comment: I'm... sorry. I can't really see this going well. What happens if I wake up, think of a golf, only to see someone's commented the exact same thing? Or if someone helped golf a byte, but then I completely revamp the approach?

Comment: This seems like a meta tag to me.

Comment: @MartinBüttner What do you mean?

Comment: @AlexA. Adding a tag to a post because the post has a certain kind of leaderboard doesn't say anything about the challenge (since, as xnor explained and jimmy explained, the actual scoring isn't any different from plain code golf, it just gives a different scale).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh, yes, agreed.

Comment: Well, I think sometimes there is an answer that looks like it will win, many people stop working on longer answers. I have no idea how I could encourage users to contribute in the language(s) they are most familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**On scoring by ratio to shortest code**

I like the philosophy here that you're competing relative to your language, but I don't see it working. The idea seems to be based on assumptions from Anarchy Golf that don't transfer:

- Most challenges have multiple submissions in each language.
- There is a fixed (though large) set of language options.
- The golfing is competitive enough that the best score well-approximates the optimal score.

On PPCG, most submissions are alone in their language and would get the best score of 1. The per-language competition is diluted by frequent challenges and a wide array of languages. Ironically, your proposed scoring method discourages such competition and encourages golfing in your made-up language that only you use.

If you're not first place in your language, you still really can't compare your score to other non-first-places. It depends on how good the first place is, which varies a lot and is outside your control. Maybe an experienced golfer tried really hard for the perfect golf in that language, or maybe not.

If you are first place, improving your answer doesn't improve your score, it just makes others' scores worse, which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can have such a thing in the leaderboard snippets. But as an objective, it isn't really much different from a regular golf. Every user can decide how they think who is the winner in their own way, but the answerers are supposed to do the same thing.

If you have a more complicated idea that is different from a regular golf, first try posting a question in the sandbox and see how it goes. Think of a tag only if those questions end up well received.